# How to correct the size of GNOME desktop wallpaper image

Tags: gnome

I have an image that is my background on my laptop. But the image is too zoomed in.  So half of the image is not showing on my laptop background.  How do I fix this? Is this a scale thing? I tried re-sizing to 250*250 and applied the new image to the background but same thing.  I am using Fedora 34 Lenovo laptop.

Comment: You haven't said what desktop manager you're using. In general terms you need to look for the option that controls how the wallpaper is displayed. There's "fill screen" (which you have at the moment) or "whole picture" (which you want). The precise names will be different, but this should get you going

Comment: using Gnome - I go to settings background and select picture but there is no "fill screen" or any other options.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1022975/473234

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by installing Tweaks with `dnf -y gnome-tweaks`